# How to set initial value for all students to present in College management system | django admin inline

Tags: django, django-admin

I am building College management system in django including features such as quiz, lms and attendance and so on.

I want list all students with status=True by default in django admin inline. So teacher dont have to hammer the status checkbox for every student, every student should be present(status=True)by default and teacher only have to uncheck the status for whom who are absent.  I have googled a lot but having hard time figuring out the solution. This is what I want:
[image]

As you can see all the students are present Status=True, this should be the default behaviour

My model:

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(settings.COURSE_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)


class AttendanceStatus(models.Model):
    attendance = models.ForeignKey(Attendance, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(settings.STUDENT_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField()
```

And here is the admin.

```
class AttendanceStatusInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AttendanceStatus
    can_delete = False
    fields = [ 'student', 'status' ]
    autocomplete_fields = [ 'student' ]


@admin.register(Attendance)
class AttendanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [ 'course', 'date']
    autocomplete_fields = ['course']
    inlines = [ AttendanceStatusInline ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can think of a "horrible hack". Give the model an "absent" boolean. Make the model save method set status=False if absent=true, set absent back to false (i.e. it never stores as true), and save. Comment carefully "for use only by admin" and maybe choose a less tempting name as long as you can label it sensibly in the admin.

Comment: status = models.BooleanField(default=True) and remigrate the table

Comment: @Akram thats not something I want brother, in admin page, Everystudent should be listed with status=True by default, its not something with model but it has to do with admin inline and formset probably

Comment: @HuzaifaQayyum so you are trying to achieve everyday it should create all student objects with status=True and the teacher when login can set the status of corresponding studenst  to False if not present.If so this can be achieved by using celery beat running everyday and create every student object.But i wont recommend your idea because it is a bad design

Comment: @Akram no when teacher login and he create new entry by clicking on add new entry in changelist of admin panel, he should be presented with all the students set to present by default. now you got me bro?

Comment: @Akram look in the picture I shared in question, my question is very simple, when creating new attendance in admin panel (by clicking on add attendance in admin changelist), all students should be listed by default, there is no celery nothing like that. Just look the picture, all I need is default listing of students, hope you got me now bro

Comment: @Akram look in picture, currently I have two students, when adding new entry, as shown in picture, you are presented with all students with default status=True, In my case I have 2 students so in picture look  you have 2 students listed and you dont have to select each student one by one.

Comment: @HuzaifaQayyum Based on my understanding you cannot achieve this in your admin pannel i think so

Comment: @Akram I am thinking of custom views in django admin though I have some confusions on achieving this. Plan is first user create the attendance after that he is redirected to another page where all the students are listed by default, but how would I implement searching and more importantly using the built in admin template with modifications would be hard as it might change tomorrow and can cause inconsistency

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, adding the argument "default='True'" to your model field will do the trick.  In the case where you find you need more than a "yes or no" but still want a default, you could do something like:

```
ATTENDANCE_CHOICES = [
    ('Present', 'Present'),
    ('Absent', 'Absent'),
    ('Late', 'Late'),
    ('Excused Absence', 'Excused Absence'),
    ]

class AttendanceStatus(models.Model):
    attendance = models.ForeignKey(Attendance, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(settings.STUDENT_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ATTENDANCE_CHOICES, default=ATTENDANCE_CHOICES[0][0])
```

This will create a dropdown for your field with a default set as the first choice in the list, in this case 'Present'. The first string in each tuple of the choices list will be saved to the database.  The second string is visible to the user, so you could change these if there is a use case.

Comment: Bro please read question again, even if I do so, I have to manually select all students one by one, I dont want that, so all students should be listed in the admin area by default as you can see in the picture, when adding new attendance, all the students are list with default status=True(means present), So problem is not setting defaults on model

Comment: Bro, please try the suggestions provided by myself and others.  You'll find these do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: brother sorry but I already googled alot and I already know that default thing and choices you shared but its not that, I am repeating again what I have asked in question, if teacher create new entry, in attendance inline section, he has to select each student one by one himself right? thats what I want to avoid, all students should be listed by default in admin inline.. And I already shared this in question. Now tell me does setting default in models help in anyway?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yup... please reread the question

Comment: If you set default=True on a boolean, it will be checked for each new student added, without the teacher selecting it.  If you follow the "choices" example, the default choice will be "Present", for each new record created, without the teacher selecting it.